# How to create new column using mutate within a custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to build a function that transforms an existing column using case_when within the mutate function. The end goal is to be able to enter the table name and column name and then append a string to the existing column name so the mutate function creates a new column. Thanks!

```
my_function <- function(table_name, col_name) {
  table_name %>%
    mutate(paste("new_",col_name) = case_when(as.numeric(col_name) <=4 ~ -1,
                                as.numeric(col_name) > 4 & as.numeric(col_name) <= 8 ~ 0,
                                as.numeric(col_name) > 8 ~ 1))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are diving in the wonderful world of tidy-evaluation, where you have to `ensym` or `enquo` the names of the columns:

```
my_function <- function(table_name, col_name) {
    .col = ensym(col_name)
    table_name %>%
        mutate(!!paste0("new_", col_name) := case_when(as.numeric(!!.col) <=4 ~ -1,
                                                  as.numeric(!!.col) > 4 & as.numeric(!!.col) <= 8 ~ 0,
                                                  as.numeric(!!.col) > 8 ~ 1))
}

df = tibble(x=1:10)
my_function(df, "x")
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       x new_x
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1    -1
 2     2    -1
 3     3    -1
 4     4    -1
 5     5     0
 6     6     0
 7     7     0
 8     8     0
 9     9     1
10    10     1
```

You can learn more about this (including operators `!!` and `:=`) on the [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) vignette.

My example used `ensym` and takes the argument as a string, to stick with your function. However, it is more common to use `enquo` and take the argument as a column name:

```
my_function2 <- function(table_name, col_name) {
    .col = enquo(col_name)
    table_name %>%
        mutate(!!paste0("new_", quo_name(.col)) := case_when(as.numeric(!!.col) <=4 ~ -1,
                                                       as.numeric(!!.col) > 4 & as.numeric(!!.col) <= 8 ~ 0,
                                                       as.numeric(!!.col) > 8 ~ 1))
}
my_function2(df, x) #no quotes on the x!
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       x new_x
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1    -1
 2     2    -1
 3     3    -1
 4     4    -1
 5     5     0
 6     6     0
 7     7     0
 8     8     0
 9     9     1
10    10     1
```

Still, shouldn't you rather build a function that takes a numeric and use it inside `mutate` ? Here is an example with `dplyr v1.0.0`:

```
my_function3 = function(x){
    case_when(as.numeric(x) <=4 ~ -1,
              as.numeric(x) > 4 & as.numeric(x) <= 8 ~ 0,
              as.numeric(x) > 8 ~ 1)
}
df %>% mutate(across(x, my_function3, .names="new_{col}"))
```